# Authenticate Using Google Sign-In on Android build it and error

Tags: android, firebase, gradle, firebase-authentication

I follow Fierbase consol instruction to add Authenticate Using Google Sign-In on Android to my app but I can't build it and error appear say to fix the version conflict either by updating the version of the google-services plugin or updating the version of com.google.android.gms to 10.0.1. 
, can any one help ??

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 25
buildToolsVersion "25.0.3"
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.mohamed71.fierbasebackendcourse"
    minSdkVersion 19
    targetSdkVersion 25
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner 
"android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 
'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
}

dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', 
{
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
})

compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:10.0.1'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:11.0.2'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:11.0.2'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:11.0.2'
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}


 apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

the other build.gradle code

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to 
 all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
repositories {
    jcenter()
}
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.3'
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.1.0'

    // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
    // in the individual module build.gradle files

}
}

allprojects {
repositories {
    jcenter()
}
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your firebase:databse version

```
com.google.firebase:firebase-database:11.0.2
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the error because

```
 compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:10.0.1'
```

and I replace it with

```
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:11.0.2'
```

and error is gone . but the strange
 is that I add firebase-database from Tool >> firebase but it didnt load the last vertion !!